# Margin Call Question

Tags: margin

Hoping for an explanation on one part of this problem:

```
Execute a margin call of 1000 shares of a stock at $40/share.
The initial margin requirement is 50% and the maintenance margin
requirement is 30%.

I hold for one year, at which time the stock is selling for $50/share
and the stock paid a dividend of $1. The interest rate on the loan was 6%
annually.

Calculate the percentage return on investment.
```

The formula I would use is:

```
R(t) = [P(t) - P(t-1) + D(t) - Interest(t)] / Initial Investment
```

And I know the answer is:

```
[50 - 40 + 1 - 1.2] / 20 = 49%
```

But I don't understand why the interest is 1.2 instead of .06.  What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Is this homework because this looks like one.

Comment: It is homework. Is that not allowed? I'm just looking for an explanation of how the interest rate is being caculated.

Comment: @MISNole It's ok to ask homework questions but it's customary to explicitly state in the question that it's homework. People may provide different context for you!

Comment: There is no margin call, you are simply asking about the math of a stock bought on margin. You didn't "Execute a margin call of 1000 shares" you just bought those shares with 50% margin. Would you like to edit or one of us can?

Comment: FWIW, A "margin call" is what happens when your position cost (or expected position cost) exceeds the amount you have with the broker. They issue a margin call to you and may liquidate your holdings or lock your account demanding more funds or both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial position is worth 40000. You post 50% margin, so you deposited 20000 and borrowed 20000. 6% of 20000 is 1200.